# pmvnorm is returning a negative number

Tags: r

I am using pmvnorm to calculate multivariate normal cdfs in R
But I am obtaining a negative number in my calculations
A probability cannot be negative. Could someone aid me in finding out a solution

The code is here

```
library(mvtnorm)
pmvnorm(lower = rep(-Inf, 2), upper = c(-5, -18),
    mean = c(0,0), sigma = matrix(c(1, -0.5, -0.5, 1),
                                  nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
```

The output is

```
[1] -2.507297e-84
attr(,"error")
[1] 1e-15
attr(,"msg")
[1] "Normal Completion"
```

Comment: It's *barely* negative

Comment: That's a numerical zero.

Comment: solution: `result <- pmax(0,result)` ...

Answer (score 3):

It's a numerical issue. You can regard it as zero or specify the `algorithm` argument to be more/less precise.

Playing around got me this:

```
library("mvtnorm")
pmvnorm(lower = rep(-Inf, 2), upper = c(-5, -18),
        mean = c(0,0), sigma = matrix(c(1, -0.5, -0.5, 1), ncol = 2),
        algorithm = Miwa(steps = 1280))
##[1] 8.447235e-132
##attr(,"error")
##[1] NA
##attr(,"msg")
##[1] "Normal Completion"
```

Consult the `?pmvnorm` documentation for more information.
So, you can either tweak the used algorithm, or do as Ben suggests in the comments.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the documentation. I don't really understand floating point arithmetic very well.